# android real comparison dp vs. px

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tablet with lcd_density 160. According to Android guide, 1 dp is equivalent 1px for LCD density 160. Tablet resolution is 1024px x 768px.

Next, according to [Android metrics and grids](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html), recommended height of the action bar is 48 dp. So when I captured screen, height of action bar was 56 px (or in this case 56 dp). Navigation bar has got the height 48 px. I tried to capture android settings, pinterest, dropbox, etc.

Is there something wrong in my calculations, or mentioned apps don't keep recommended height 48dp? Why does it 56 px?

Comment: What do you get for `DisplayMetrics.ydpi`? 160 is one of the bucket sizes, and may not be the actual density of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1dp on MDPI device equals 1px, that is correct.
I just did some calculations by myself (my Android tablets LCD density is 160, as mentioned in build.prop) and it does seem like you're telling the truth.
To make sure I just started a new, 100% project in eclipse, I didn't change anything at all, launched it on my tablet, took a screenshot and it's still 56px. Then I looked for properties of an action bar: 48dp exactly.

My tablet runs 100% pure version of AOSP Android 4.1.2.

lcd_density 160 in build.prop, rechecked twice.

My only hypothesis: 1dp on 160ppi is NOT EXACTLY 1px.

Comment: Okay, I did everything alike. I got also LCD density from build.prop. Now, try to look on height of navigation bar. What is the size?

Comment: Action bar and navigation bar have the same heights? Action bar is up and navigation bar is down. I have different heights for it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misunderstood you. 44px, phablet mode.